# How to convert Json response to a map in angular 5?

Tags: json, angular5

I am new to angular little confused,
When I am calling the Rest API, Getting the JSON response 
But I need to store that JSON response into a `(Map<string, string>)`,
cloud please help to fix this.

**Edit 1:**

On calling `api/user/id` getting below json response

```
{
"firstname":"test",
"lastname":"testlastname",
"email":"test@test.com",
"username":"ufk",
"password":"qweasd",
"phone":"123456789"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below code to solve, JSON response directly sending to a map

```
return this.http.get('/api/user/' + ID, options)

       .map((response: Response) => {
       return response.json() as User;
      }).toPromise().then(x => {
     this.user= x;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Service.ts:**

```
public getJSONResponse(): Observable<Map> {
    return this.http.get<Map>('api's end point');
}
```

**Model:**

```
export class Map{//sample Model
    firstname : string
    lastname : string
    email : string
    username : string
    password : string
    phone : string       
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement based on snippet code, But still facing the issue. I am updating the code above